# Generate records based on a condition during projection in Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I would like to generate records from an existing schema based on a condition
e.g. I want to do something like

```
A = load 'data' using PigStorage() as (f1:int, f2:int);
B = foreach A generate ( f1 == 0 ? null : A);
```

What will be an appropriate method to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by "generate" records? Based on the syntax you provided your not generating any new records. Just looping over all the records in A and applying a bincond. Granted you can't reference A in the bincond. You would want to switch it to something like (f1 == 0 ? null : f1); In which case you might as well just use a FILTER instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate B as follow:

```
SPLIT A INTO B IF f1 != 0;
```

See also [SPLIT documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#SPLIT).

Answer (score 0):

```
A = load 'data' using PigStorage() as (f1:int, f2:int);

B = filter A by f1 != 0 ;
```